# The risk of allowing users to add post with raw html which will be purified using HTMLPurifier

Tags: php, wysiwyg

Thanks for checking

In my social site i use summernote for commenting and posts. then i use htmlpurifier to sanitize user posts. But i want to allow user to add music from hulkshare. since summernote does not support it i thought of allowing users to do so by pasting iframe code from hulkshare in the codeview of summernote.

Please is htmlpurifire strong enough to protect my site from XSS attacks from users.

Comment: Clarify what is `HTMLPurifier` first. Is this question related to user posted HTML or to enabling users to post `hulkshare` snippets?

Comment: HTMLPurifier is fine for this, but whether it is secure enough depends on the filtering rules you write.

Comment: The best solution is to parse yourself a pre-defined code and render it into what you want. You'll gain more control on user input and on the render.

Answer (score 3):

HTMLPurifier logically will remove any iframe, so it cannot work. Why not create a new HTML tag, specific to your website for this. Something like:

```
<yourwebsite-music source="hulkshare" id="1234"/>
```

Then you set HTMLpurifier to leave this tag and your render it yourself using PHP (by replacing the tag with an iframe). Doing so will also allow you to add other media sources later on, and it gives you more control over what's happening in user's posts.

Comment: i already have an Iframe working. which i use to allow users upload youtube videos. i use phpQuery to select the iframe(one iframe is allowed for each post) save in a variable, run purifier on the remaining html, strip up any script from the Ifram and insert it back to the html. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I would do custom tag for users like @Music-urlHere or {MUSIC,url} and parse it in backend

Comment: thats a nice approach but i am using summernote so it will renderd @ to html code.

Answer (score 0):

There are many html purifier libraries, in which you can specify the prohibited/allowed tags. I suggest you look them up and choose the best for your case.